# Why the Shape pointed by pb is destroyed when an exception is thrown in the example below?

Tags: c++, destructor, auto-ptr

This example was taken from Stroustup's book, third edition, Section 14.4.2 :

```
void f (Point p1, Point p2, auto_ptr<Circle> pc, Shape* pb)
{
    auto_ptr<Shape> p (new Rectangle(p1 ,p2));
    auto_ptr<Shape> pbox(pb);
    p->rotate(45);
    / / ...
    if (in_a_mess ) throw Mess();
    / / ...
}
```

"Here the Rectangle, the Shape pointed to by pb, and the Circle pointed to by pc are deleted
whether or not an exception is thrown."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's destroyed because that's what `auto_ptr` does. It destroys the pointed-to object in its destructor, and the destructor is called when the `auto_ptr` leaves scope, whether or not an exception is thrown. That's just how C++ works.

Internally, `auto_ptr` is essentially (relevant bits only):

```
template <typename T>
struct auto_ptr
{
    auto_ptr(T* ptr) : m_ptr(ptr) {}
    ~auto_ptr() { delete m_ptr; }
private:
    T* m_ptr;
};
```

Comment: @user1162978: Because you've put it in an `auto_ptr` and `auto_ptr` deletes things when the `auto_ptr` is destroyed.

Comment: So pb is destroyed because pbox is destroyed. Is that what you're saying ?

Comment: @user1162978: That's exactly right. `pbox` grabs onto `pb` and says "if I go down, I'm taking you with me, no matter what."